# Como criar uma relação 1:N e 1:1 dentro da mesma tabela?

Tags: sql, tabela-banco-de-dados

Eu tenho uma tabela para registro de imagens que é utilizada como chave estrangeira para outras tabelas. O problema é que em uma dessas tabelas (PROMOCOES) a relação é de 1:N (uma promoção para N imagens ), enquanto nas demais tabelas a relação é de 1:1.
Minha dúvida está em como organizar essas tabelas pois não posso utilizar chave estrangeira dentro da tabela de imagens. Dessa forma seria melhor eu criar uma tabela especifica de imagens de promoções, ou criar uma tabela intermediaria entre PROMOCOES  e imagens e continuar utilizando uma unica tabela de imagens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pelas [regras de normalização](http://www.luis.blog.br/normalizacao-de-dados-e-as-formas-normais.aspx) deverias ter uma chave estrangeira na tabela imagens. Mas se não podes ter essa chave podes criar uma tabela que relacione imagens e promoções continuando a utilizar a tabela de imagens.

```
+----------+-----------+
| promo_id | imagem_id |
+----------+-----------+
```

É a forma mais simples de fazer, isto claro se não der mesmo para colocar chave estrangeira na tabela imagens. Ah e não te esqueças de por como chave primaria as 2 colunas desta tabela.

Comment: O problema de utilizar chave estrangeira é que seria necessário uma chave para cada tabela que utiliza imagem.

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow PT! Sim, eu percebi isso. Eu quando isso me acontece crio uma tabela que relacione as 2 tabelas, mas sem chave estrangeira.

Comment: Obrigado, essa parece ser a melhor prática.